# How to switch to occur buffer in Emacs automatically?

Tags: emacs, elisp

When running on `occur` on a regex, the frame splits into two windows and the `occur` buffer is shown below. However, the keyboard focus is still in the original buffer. How can I change this behavior programmatically, such that the `occur` buffer becomes the current buffer? I tried this:

```
(defun test-occur ()
  (interactive)
  (occur "test")
  (switch-to-buffer "*Occur*"))
```

but it does not work.. (That is: now the `occur` buffer is shown both in the top and the bottom window)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
(defun test-occur ()
  (interactive)
  (occur "test")
  (other-window 1))
```

Comment: Thanks it works. What if there where more than two windows. How to choose the correct one?

Comment: It choses the most recent one. Occur should be the most recent in your case

Answer (score 5):

You do not have to define a separate function for that.
Just add a hook:

```
(add-hook 'occur-hook (lambda () (other-window 1)))
```

[Alternatively](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/13212/795), and, probably, more reliably:

```
(add-hook 'occur-hook (lambda () (switch-to-buffer-other-window "*Occur*")))
```

Comment: I had problems with this approach and needed to call the window by name: `(add-hook 'occur-hook
          '(lambda ()
             (switch-to-buffer-other-window "*Occur*")))` https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/13212/how-to-make-occur-mode-select-the-window-of-buffer-occur